# Mock Lodash orderBy method using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, lodash

My AngularJS directive includes a call to the Lodash orderBy method and I need to mock it in the unit test. The Karma config includes Lodash in the list of files to be loaded in the browser.

```
    spyOn(_, 'orderBy').and.callFake((test, [], []) => {
        return test;
    });
```

Attempting to mock orderBy method fails with:

```
Error: <spyOn> : orderBy() method does not exist
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you configured a provider for loadsh in your app?

Comment: Do you inject lodash at the beginning of your test?

Comment: Everything works ok when mocking the debounce call. Is there smth special about the orderBy method?

Comment: The method `orderBy` was introduced as part of 4.X version. It didn't existed in 3.X and 2.X. So please check what version do you use.

Comment: My setup is the same as http://plnkr.co/edit/r7P25jKzEFgE5j10bZgE?p=preview, only difference being that I'm using spyOn and mocking the orderBy method. I am using lodash 4.17.4.

Comment: Please update the Planker to be as it's in your project, then I'll find the issue.